# Intellij filewatcher is compiling scss to CSS but is not updating server files

Tags: intellij-idea

I have a compass scss file watcher setup

[image]

the files compile fine, but the produced CSS is not deployed to the server

I always manually have to deploy the folder, or like I did, I wrote a small ant script to do it for me. None the less, not what I want, this should get auto deployed

Answer (score 1):

Make sure to tick the 'Upload external changes' checkbox in Deployment/Options.
See http://www.jetbrains.com/webstorm/webhelp/deployment.html and related topics for more info

Comment: hmm but that has further consequences, right?  even though this is probably correct most of the time for me, this will eventually break something when i dont want it to happen